# How do you append a row of data to a list

Tags: python, csv, arraylist, append

For example...
The following are stored in a dictionary variable called ID_DATA

```
[0,John,male,$2400]
[1,mary,female,$2700]
[2,janie,female,$6790]
[3,adex,male,$3300]
[4,julie,female,$5400]
```

I want to loop through the list and append only the rows with only male in another list variable called ID_MALE

Can anyone help out ???.

Comment: There is no dictionary shown in your question. Are you reading this data from a CSV file, as suggested by your tag? Please show exactly how you are reading this data and what format you are storing it in, and also show your expected output.

Comment: It's from a CSV file

Answer (score 0):

Are they stored in a dictionary of lists or a list of lists?

If it's the latter and the gender is always in the 2nd spot in each list (the second column) then you could just do something like this:

```
ID_DATA = [['John','male','$2400'],['mary','female','$2700'],['janie','female','$6790'],['adex','male','$3300'],['julie','female','$5400']]
ID_MALE = []
for row in ID_DATA:
    if row[2] == 'male':
       ID_MALE.append(row)

print(ID_MALE)
```

Which prints

```
[['John', 'male', '$2400'], ['adex', 'male', '$3300']]
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use list tuples first for saving data
then use lambda and filter

```
data_Id= [
       [0,'John','male',2400],
       [1,'mary','female',2700],
       [2,'janie','female',6790],
       [3,'adex','male',3300],
       [4,'julie','female',5400]
       ]
    str='male'

   ID_MALE =filter(lambda x:str in x,data_Id)
   print(list(ID_MALE))
```

Output

```
[[0, 'John', 'male', 2400], [3, 'adex', 'male', 3300]]
```